# Changing tableview frames with animation using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

i am trying to change tableview frame by using autolayout in animationWithDuration block. Like That;

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

            weekdayOffersVerticalConstraint.constant = 80;
            [headerView layoutIfNeeded];
            [weekdayTableView layoutIfNeeded];

            self.isTableViewSmall = YES;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


        }];
```

my tableview's frames are changing with this code block, but when i scroll to down, cells coming from left side to right side, i thought it is about with `[weekdayTableView layoutIfNeeded];` layoutIfNeeded effect to all subviews. How can i obstruct to effect to my tableview's cells?

Sorry for my bad english, Thank you very much for your answers and advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `layoutIfNeeded` before you begin the animation to update the constraints:

```
[headerView layoutIfNeeded];
[weekdayTableView layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

            weekdayOffersVerticalConstraint.constant = 80;
            [headerView layoutIfNeeded];
            [weekdayTableView layoutIfNeeded];

            self.isTableViewSmall = YES;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //
        }];
```

You probably also don't want to set that `BOOL` property inside the animation block unless you have a method that overrides it intentionally during the animation.